# 1 Way Anova Test in R incorrect df

Tags: r, anova

I want to run an anova test in R to find out if there's a difference in the number of weeks of each brand. My code is as follows:

```
weeks = c(100,96,92,96,92,76,80,75,84,82,108,100,96,98,100)
brand = c('a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c')
battery.exp = data.frame(brand, weeks)
test.1 = aov(battery.exp$weeks~battery.exp$brand)
summary(test.1)
```

I'm getting incorrect results in the summary. The df of the brand should be 2, but my output says 3. Does anyone know why I would get incorrect results in my anova test? I've also tried to replace the second to last line with the following:

```
test.1 = aov(battery.exp$weeks~factor(battery.exp$brand))
```

but that also didn't solve the problem. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The default is to use a model with an intercept which means you need to use a reference level for your categorical variable so you only have two free parameters. If you don't want to use an intercept, you can explicitly request an intercept free model with

```
summary(aov(weeks~brand-1, battery.exp))
```

(note the `-1` in the formula)

Comment: alternatively you could also write `summary(aov(weeks~brand+0, battery.exp))
`